# The current project.json path in core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm copying some files in a .net core project by including them in a project,  setting the build action to "content" and set to "always copy", and want to refer to those files from the project. In .Net framework, a relative path such as "foo.zip" would refer to a file that's copied to the output directory. However, the file is copied in the project directory, not the output directory with the DLL. E.g. foo.zip would be put alongside the source files, whilst the output dll would be "bin/Debug|Release/netcoreapp1.0".  Using a relative path of "foo.zip" in code refers to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\foo.zip"

Is this intended? If so, is there a way I can access the directory of the output? The closest I've found is `AppContext.BaseDirectory` which refers to the netcoreapp1.0 directory, but that wouldn't work when the project is "published"

Update: after some experimentation, the build action of content was responsible for copying the file to the source directory which seems odd. Setting it to "none" performed as expected, and copied the file to the output directory. Is this path pointing to the IDE directory as expected?

Comment: Wait two weeks .. vs2017 RC will kill this issues.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to include the file in the output by using he publishOptions section in the project.json:

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": "foo.zip"
},
```

The file should then be in the same relative location at runtime as it is when you are writing code.

Answer (score 0):

> Update: after some experimentation, the build action of content was
>   responsible for copying the file to the source directory which seems
>   odd. Setting it to "none" performed as expected, and copied the file
>   to the output directory. Is this path pointing to the IDE directory as
>   expected?

The fact the build action of content copy the file to the source directoty is expected and useful. For example when you are developping a Website with MVC, it is common that your views (*.cshtml* files) are located in the *Views* directory of your source directory, next to the *Controllers* and *Models* directories.

Now you are running the Web application from Visual Studio and you just want to change some texts in your HTML page. You can simply edit the *.cshtml* file under Visual Studio and save it. **Your change will appear directly after you refresh the page in the web browser.** There is no need to compile and launch the Web application again which save a lot of time in Web development.